# Convergence and sum of an infinite series: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{24 i-4 i^2-35}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

Determine whether the following series is convergent or divergent. If convergent, find the sum.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{24 i-4 i^2-35}$$

Since the limit of the series is zero, I know that it is not divergent (divergence test).

How do i prove that the series is convergent, and futhermore, find the sum?

I rewrote the series (using partial fraction decomposition) as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{24 i-4 i^2-35}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1/4i-10(-(1/4 i-7))}$$

But I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Why do you think this kind of math formatting is acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack exchange and I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You may use a partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\frac{6}{24 i-4 i^2-35}=\frac{3}{2 i-5}-\frac{3}{2 (i-1)-5}
$$
then you may observe that the series is a [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general) one:

> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{6}{24 i-4 i^2-35}=\frac{3}{2 n-5}+\frac35,\qquad n\geq1,
> $$

then the conclusion is direct.

Comment: @Hvb123 You are welcome! Have a look at this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series